# how to serialize a YamlDocument to yaml string

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, yamldotnet

I use YamlDotnet and I have a YamlDocument. Now I want to convert it to his yaml text representation in memory but I don't see how to achieve that.

```
var yaml = new YamlDocument(new YamlMappingNode());
yaml.Add("one", "other")
var text = yaml.ToYamlText()
```

and I should get in text something like :

```
one: "other"
```

I tried zith Serializer class but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I found the solution in unit test of the source code :

```
var yaml = new YamlDocument(new YamlMappingNode());
yaml.Add("one", "other");
var yamlStream = new YamlStream(yaml);
var buffer = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(buffer))
{
    yamlStream.Save(writer);
    yamlText = writer.ToString();
}
```

Anyway, I have now another problem, I need all my values to be surrounded by double quotes. In another application I was using a QuoteSurroundingEventEmitter : ChainedEventEmitter with an object graph selrialization. But with yamlStream.Save() I don't see how to implement this mecanism

Comment: Instead of adding a string, add a `YamlScalarNode` and set its Style property: `mapping.Add("one", new YamlScalarNode("other") { Style = ScalarStyle.DoubleQuoted });`. See a fully working example here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/YZlsc1

Comment: Yes it’s what I’ve finally done. Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @AntoineAubry quick question, when I use YamlStream.Save I got, as output result, strange random string before or after the key like this one : &1887939252. Any Idea why ?

Comment: ok again I found the reason why. Need to pass false as the second parameter of Save...

Comment: `YamlDocument` doesn't appear to have an `Add` method.  Did something change?